# expect res.json not being called with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using Jest to unit test a node js function, however in the end, i'm expecting res.json to have been called, but that does not occur. It says that the number of calls of res.json is 0.  Here is the function to test:

```
      try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.body.id });
        if (user) {
          let userToUpdate = user;
          userToUpdate.defaultCard = req.body.idCard;
          try {
            await User.updateOne({ _id: req.body.id }, userToUpdate);
            console.log("b");
            return res.json({ message: "Default succesfull" });
          } catch (error) {
            return res.json({ message: "error" });
          }
        } else {
          console.log("d");
          res.json({ message: "error" });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("e");
        console.log(e);
        res.json({ message: "error" });
      }
    })
```

And here is my testing function:

```
 let req = {
      headers: {
        authtoken: "fakeToken",
      },
      body: {
        id: "fakeUserId",
        idCard: "fakeCardId",
      },
    };
    let res = {
      json: jest.fn(),
    };
    const find_one_mock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(req.body.id);
    const update_one_mock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(req.body);
    User.mockImplementation(() => ({
      findOne: find_one_mock,
      updateOne: update_one_mock,
    }));

    const fakeUser = { _id: "fakeUserId", defaultCard: "oldCardId" };
    
   
    User.findOne.mockResolvedValue(fakeUser);
    User.updateOne.mockResolvedValue(fakeUser);

    await makeDefaultCard(req, res);
    await Promise.resolve();

    expect(User.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ _id: "fakeUserId" });
    expect(User.updateOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      message: "Default succesfull",
    });
```

Comment: Don't unit test controllers. Most of that logic should be extracted to a business domain layer (and separate persistence layer), leaving only transport-related code you can test at the integration level.

Comment: I'm new to unit testing, can you explain more what you mean with your reponse?

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you explain a bit please ? I'm facing almost the same issue.

Comment: Mocking things you don't own, in this case Express's Request and Response objects, is a smell. Instead, you decouple the Express transport layer handling from the actual business logic from the DB persistence layer, so you can unit test the middle part and integration test the rest. I've written about testing and designing APIs [here](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2023/May/23/js-tdd-ohm.html).